# How can I curl a website using TLS1.0 or TLS 1.1 and is no longer supported on my shared hosting?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

There's a website maintained by another company, and this site is still using TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1. My site should communicate with this site through shared hosting, which has disabled TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 with its last upgrade.

**Do I have a chance to keep the connection alive** knowing it's extremely insecure and vulnerable **?**

I'm using PHP7.4 with cURL7.64.0 and OpenSSL/1.1.1d as you can see below.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'somedata');
        if (is_array($postData)) {
            foreach ($postData as $key => $value) {
                $postData[$key] = utf8_decode($value);
            }

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
        }
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
```

(I would leave it to the company to worry about the vulnerability as they don't care about anything, like not upgrading their TLS version.)

Comment: *"... knowing it's __extremely__ insecure and vulnerable ..."* - It is not. It is slightly insecure only. Any attacks are far from trivial and far from cheap.

Comment: Can you post the version of curl and OpenSSL?

Comment: Likely it is disabled not in code but as default security level. Try `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1');`

Comment: I tried what @SteffenUllrich suggested, and it didn't help, httpCode is still 0.

Comment: @ChrisHaas the post has been edited, I use cURL7.64.0 and OpenSSL/1.1.1d.

Comment: What’s in `$output` after the exec?

Comment: ```$output``` is false after exec.